# Не могу отобразить xml в виде таблицы в браузере

Tags: c#, html, xml, xslt

Имеется xml и xslt файлы. Открываю xml в браузере и он отображается как обычно, но не как таблица. В чем ошибка?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?> 
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSLTFile1.xsl" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="Stylesheet1.css"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <izdelia>
    <material>сталь</material>
    <number>1</number>
    <length>1</length>
    <width>2</width>
    <heigth>3</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дерево</material>
    <number>2</number>
    <length>2</length>
    <width>3</width>
    <heigth>4</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>пластмасса</material>
    <number>3</number>
    <length>4</length>
    <width>5</width>
    <heigth>6</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>ольха</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>100</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дубо</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуба</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дубо</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуба</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
</NewDataSet>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:template match="NewDataSet">
    <html>
     <body>
      <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
          <td align="center"><strong>Материал</strong></td>
          <td align="center"><strong>Количество</strong></td>
          <td align="center"><strong>Длина</strong></td>
          <td align="center"><strong>Ширина</strong></td>
          <td align="center"><strong>Высота</strong></td>
        </tr>
       <xsl:for-each select="NewDataSet/izdelia">
        <tr bgcolor="#F5F5F5">
          <td><xsl:value-of select="material"/></td>
          <td align="right"><xsl:value-of select="number"/> <xsl:value-of select="number/@caption"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="length"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="width"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="heigth"/></td>
        </tr>
       </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
     </body>
    </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

NewDataSet { display: table }
izdelia { display: table-row }
material, number,length, width, heigth { display: table-cell }
```

Comment: Это скриптовый файл (php)?

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V Файл *.xml файл и *.xslt файл

Comment: И внизу еще добавил файл Stylesheet1.css

Comment: разве xml не должен быть в UTF-8?

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V Не знаю, если поменять то все равно не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего Вы забыли указать в header тип возвращаемого документа. Через PHP его можно указать так:

```
<?php header ("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"); ?>
```

Наверное можно и через .htaccess, но я не знаю как. Поищите найдете.
Проверьте что Вам возвращает браузер в header через F12 (Сеть -> Заголовки).

Comment: а на шарпе как?

Comment: Вариантов много может быть, я в ASP .net не на столько силен.
`response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");
` А лучше всего идите на msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525208%28v=vs.90%29.aspx